# Why does UPDATE statement always produce "datatype mismatch" error?

Tags: sql, vb.net

The statement below causes a "data type mismatch" error, and I don't know why.  Can you help me fix it?

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE C_DETAILS" & " SET C_ID='" & Me.C_ID.Text & "',C_NAME='" & Me.C_NAME.Text & "', C_FATHER='" & Me.C_FATHER.Text & "',C_PHONE= '" & Me.C_PHONE.Text & "',C_GENDER='" & Me.C_GENDER.Text & "',C_DOB='" & Me.C_DOB.Text & "',C_ADDRESS='" & Me.C_ADDRESS.Text & "'" & "WHERE C_ID=" & Me.C_ID.Text & ""
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What data type is `C_ID` in the table?

Here you reference it as a string (by wrapping the value in single-quotes):

```
... SET C_ID='" & Me.C_ID.Text & "' ...
```

Here you reference it as a numeric (no single-quotes):

```
... WHERE C_ID=" & Me.C_ID.Text & ""
```

It can't be both.  So one of these two is incorrect.

---

Also, and **this is important**, the code you've shown in the question represents a [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which is one of the most common and dangerous security vulnerabilities in software today.  Please use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.  Direct string concatenation like that should *never* be used in production code.

Answer (score 0):

Since in `where` , you have not used single quote, implies, it is a `int` field, and it shown error for update. So assuming it is `int` field, you can use following line as a replace for your code.

`cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE C_DETAILS" & " SET C_ID=" & Me.C_ID.Text & ",C_NAME='" & Me.C_NAME.Text & "', C_FATHER='" & Me.C_FATHER.Text & "',C_PHONE= '" & Me.C_PHONE.Text & "',C_GENDER='" & Me.C_GENDER.Text & "',C_DOB='" & Me.C_DOB.Text & "',C_ADDRESS='" & Me.C_ADDRESS.Text & "'" & "WHERE C_ID=" & Me.C_ID.Text & ""`

And , this can be true, `C_ID` might be a string/varchar field, then you need to use following.

`cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE C_DETAILS" & " SET C_ID='" & Me.C_ID.Text & "',C_NAME='" & Me.C_NAME.Text & "', C_FATHER='" & Me.C_FATHER.Text & "',C_PHONE= '" & Me.C_PHONE.Text & "',C_GENDER='" & Me.C_GENDER.Text & "',C_DOB='" & Me.C_DOB.Text & "',C_ADDRESS='" & Me.C_ADDRESS.Text & "'" & "WHERE C_ID='" & Me.C_ID.Text & "'"`